# Userform control error: object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with 2 frames. Each frame has a command button that adds a frame to that parent frame.

On the first command button click event the addition is successful, but on the 2nd I get an error.

```
Private Sub frame1Button_Click()
    'add frame to frame 1
    Set frm = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "1")
End Sub

Private Sub frame2Button_Click()
    'add frame to frame2 - this generates error
    Set frm = Me.Frame2.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "2")
End Sub
```

The error is:

> description: "Automation error 
>   The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."
>   Number: -2147417848

Comment: Even with valid control names ("1" and "2" aren't), I get the same error, or Excel squarely crashes, on the latest version of Excel 2016-32bit. It only occurs for "Forms.Frame.1". I will now delete my answer so as to increase your chances of getting feedback.

Comment: I've given it another spin tonight and must conclude that dynamically added Frames within Frames just don't work. If you absolutely need them, you can add them to the Form's Controls collection and position them over the existing frames. You may get a funny Tab order, though.