# Error when adding dynamic controls to a frame in an Excel VBA Userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Userform with two Frames. Lets call them "Frame1" and "Frame2".
If I add controls to one of the two frames with a class module (I need the events) then I get a runtime error.

If I delete "Frame2" or add it during the runtime it works just fine (no solution..I need the controls in both frames).

In the code below I don't even use "Frame2"... still the same Problem

If I try to add the controls to a frame that was added during runtime it is also the same problem. Would be best case if I could add it to a frame that was created in runtime

code in Userform:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oKlasseExcel(30) As CControls

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

  Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 30
        Set oKlasseExcel(i) = New CControls
        Set oKlasseExcel(i).TestFrames = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", , True)
    Next

End Sub
```

class module "CControls":

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents TestFrames As MSForms.frame


Sub TestFrames_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    'Code after DblClick

End Sub
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Appears to be a bug, see http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?28257-Run-time-error-2147417848-(80010108)&p=214848&viewfull=1#post214848

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879572/userform-control-error-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients